# How do I hide login link and show logout link in homepage navbar once user logs in and gets re-directed to homepage?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring boot based web application and the homepage contains a boostrap navbar with Login and Register link.

Once user logs in (by clicking login link from homepage), they will be re-directed to home page again (unless they visit any other link before spring security kicks in for A&A). On re-direct, I want to hide login and register links from the navbar and show logout link in their place. Becuase I want to insert the navbar in all the pages of application.

I want to know what is the best/standard way of doing this when the requirement is re-direction to same page.

One solution that I can think of is to check and obtain a user-principal  object from spring security, pass it to thymeleaf template and check that if userprincipal object is present in the request attribute to the thymeleaf template, that means a user has logged in and I can then hide(not-render) login & register links and show(render) logout link. If not, show login & register links and hide logout link. I'm wondering, is this a correct way to do so? This feels like a hack to me and hence want to know if there is any standard way of doing this.

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried. If successful login hide login and display logout through selectors

Comment: yes that is the way to do it. it doesn't seem hack to me. because you are using mvc framework.

Comment: Through mvc you need to check for auth and token. change the state if you have active token

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have used the thymeleaf-extras spring security extensions as suggested by @Simon Martinelli below and it is working out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Thymeleaf Spring Security extension that you can use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add the namespace

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

And then you can use it:

```
        <li sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-light" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" sec:authentication="name">
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="pl-3" th:href="@{/password}">Passwort ändern</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="pl-3" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Please find the whole documentation here:

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

Comment: Yeah it's great :-)